# Find the Distribution of a Function of a Multivariate Normal

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following question.

Suppose $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Let $Y= AX +b$, where $A$ is an $n \times k$ matrix of constants and $b$ is an $n$ vector of constants. Let $W=DX +c$, where $D$ is an $m \times k$ matrix of constants and $c$ is an $m$ vector of constants. Let

\begin{equation}
S= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
Y\\
W
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

a) Find the distribution of Y

b) Find the distribution of S

So getting the distribution of Y seems fairly straightforward- we use the result that a linear transformation of a multivariate normal is multivariate normal.

But for S, can we conclude that this is multivariate normal as well, by the same result? More specifically, how can we say that Y and W are jointly multivariate normal?

I was thinking that if Y and W are independent, one can say that they are jointly multivariate normal, but they can't be independent since they both depend on X.

Comment: Hint: can you write $S$ in the form $UX+d$ for an $(n+m) \times k$ matrix $U$ and $n+m$-vector $d$?

Comment: If each of two variables is a stochastic variable i.e. each variable has its independence and yet governed by other factors. Assume the case of husband and wife - two variables in terms of health or weight for example.The outcome is jointly multivariate normal.